# Springboot crud Repository inserting null values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Springboot inserting null values in if i use crud repository even though everything configured correctly and hibernate queries are executing in console but if we check database values for amount and category are inserted as NULL values

Ticket.java

```
package com.vinay.api.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Ticket")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private double amount;
    private String category;

}
```

TicketDao.java

```
package com.vinay.api.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.vinay.api.model.Ticket;

public interface TicketDao extends CrudRepository<Ticket, Integer>{

}
```

TicketController.java

```
package com.vinay.api.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.vinay.api.dao.TicketDao;
import com.vinay.api.model.Ticket;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tickets")
public class TicketController {

    @Autowired
    private TicketDao ticketDao;

    @PostMapping("/bookTickets")
    public String bookTicket(@RequestBody List<Ticket> tickets)
    {
        ticketDao.saveAll(tickets);
        return "tickets booked: "+tickets.size();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getTickets")
    public List<Ticket> getTickets()
    {
        return (List<Ticket>) ticketDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

SpringMysqlApplication.java

```
package com.vinay.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMysqlApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMysqlApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticket
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-mysql</name>
    <description>Springboot mysql</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: did you check the data that enters the controller? (ref `@RequestBody List<Ticket> tickets`)

Comment: how to check that

Comment: You can add logging or set a breakpoint for the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this issue i didn't configure lambok in my IDE so i used manual getters and setters removed the @getter and @Setter annotations helped me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying generation type stretegy.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Also use wrapper class instead of primitive datatype. Change int to Integer.

```
private Integer id
```